# Is it possible to change the position of "otherwise" in "you wouldn't have otherwise had"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

The sentence is :

> It gives you opportunity you would not have ***otherwise*** had.

1- The role of "***otherwise***" is conj. Now my question is if we bring the "otherwise" **before** **"you"** or **put it at the end of sentence**, the meaning of the whole sentence changes?

2- why in the above sentence the "otherwise" is placed ***between*** "have" and "had"?

Answer (score 2):

These are grammatically correct and essentially the same in meaning:

- It gives you an opportunity you **otherwise** would not have had.
- It gives you an opportunity you would not have **otherwise** had.
- It gives you an opportunity you would not have had **otherwise**.

This one is wrong and has no clear meaning:

- It gives you an opportunity **otherwise** you would not have had.

This one is not grammatically wrong, but is poorly-worded:

- It gives you an opportunity you would **otherwise** not have had.